# puppet, set template variable based on hostname value or unique random value

Tags: puppet

I want to deploy a config file on several linux machines and need to make sure that a certain variable in that config file has a unique value for each machine. Until now I've been shipping the same config file the following way:

```
file {
    "/etc/nxserver/node.conf":
    mode => 644,
    ensure => file,
    source => "puppet:///modules/nxserver/nxserver-node.conf";
}
```

I assume that switching to templates is as easy as replacing the `source` with `content`:

```
file {
    "/etc/nxserver/node.conf":
    mode => 644,
    group => root,
    content => template("nxserver/nxserver-node.erb"),

}
```

In the `nxserver-node.erb` file I could set the variable of interest the following way:

```
# This file is managed by puppet
... random config stuff ...
somevariable = <%= hostname %>
```

My questions:

- Is there a way to process & extract parts of `<%= hostname %>` inside the erb file? E.g. my hostnames could be "desktop-01234", and I would want to use the "01234" bit only. How would I achieve this?
- Alternatively, could I specify a range of valid values that get uniquely but randomly assigned to the variable inside the erb file? E.g. `somevariable` could be a variable representing some port number, in the range of 1000 - 4000. I need to make sure that on each puppet host this variable has a different value. How would I achieve this?

**EDIT:** I can use
`fqdn_rand(MAX, [SEED])` to generate a random number that's unique for each hostname, but according to the docs it will return a `random whole number greater than or equal to 0 and less than MAX`.

```
<% Puppet::Parser::Functions.function('fqdn_rand') -%>
<% value = scope.function_fqdn_rand(['10000']) -%>
somevariable=<%= value.to_s %>
```

I've tried using `+` as well as `add` to add an offset but `+` seems to be reserved for strings and the `add` function is unknown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the following does exactly what I need:

```
<% Puppet::Parser::Functions.function('fqdn_rand') -%>
<% offset = "1000".to_i -%>
<% value = scope.function_fqdn_rand(['10000']).to_i + offset -%>
somevariable=<%= value.to_s %>
```

Comment: Is this not an elaborate way to say `somevariable=<%= scope.function_fqdn_rand(['10000']).to_i + 1000 %>` ?

Comment: yes but you'll get the following error "Detail: can't convert Fixnum into String". above solution works.

Comment: Right, forgot your final `to_s` :-) The first line should be safe to skip though.

Comment: unfortunately that's not enough. the `+ 1000` is actually causing the problem, my guess is that ruby interprets the `+` as having to concatenate two strings. So both offset and value need to be converted  to integers with`to_i` explicitly. only at the end you do a `to_s`.

Answer (score 0):

In ERB templates, you can do everything Ruby can. The [String](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/String.html) methods are especially helpful.

For example, to cut the prefix from your hostname, you could use

```
somevariable = <%= @hostname.sub(/^desktop-/, '') %>
```